# Treewalker iteration

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to skip iteration in current subtree and jump to the next node using treewalker?
example

```
<nav>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
    </ul>
    <p>paragraph</p>
</nav>
```

and js

```
var nav=document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];
    var tree=document.createTreeWalker(nav,NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,null,false);
    tree.firstChild(); // first paragraph
    tree.nextSibling(); // ul
    tree.firstChild(); // first li chid of ul
    tree.nextNode()||tree.nextSibling() // both return next li
```

Is there any way how to stop iteration of subtree and jump straight to the another paragraph after treewalker hits first LI element?

Comment: Are you asking for `tree.parentNode() && tree.nextSibling()` or are you looking for a way to exclude the children of an `<ul>` from the tree entirely?

Comment: im asking about excluding the children of an UL entirely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter):

```
var filter = {
    acceptNode: function(n) {
        return n && n.parentNode && n.parentNode.tagName != "UL"
          ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
          : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
    }
};
var tree=document.createTreeWalker(nav, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, filter, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a node such as `UL` and want to just skip its children, then you want to try to go in the next sibling direction. But if there's no next sibling, you need to go up another level and try again. (Eventually, you may reach the root of the walker, in which case you need to stop the iteration and return null.)

```
function nextNodeSkipChildren(tree) {
   var node;
   while (1) {
     if (node = tree.nextSibling()) return node; // return sibling if present
     if (!tree.parentNode()) return null;        // go up another level and repeat
   }
}
```

If you are already on a child node (such as `LI`) and want to skip the rest of the siblings and continue with "uncles" or "great-uncles", then just go back up to the parent before the above:

```
function nextNodeSkipRemainingSiblings(tree) {
  return tree.parentNode() && nextNodeSkipChildren(tree);
}
```

Comment: Using treewalker or nodeIteratior , every element has parentNode (in nodeIteration the first one is root passed into function so it can or dont have to have parent ) so the first condition is always true , but what if element has only one child? that child element wouldnt have siblings so the second condition would be also true thus this conditions would also return elements with just one child , or am i wrong?

Comment: No, the element that you started with with not be considered to have a parent for purposes of treewalking, so the first condition handles the case where you have gone back up to the top. From the docs for `parentNode`: "If no such node exists, or if it is before that the root node defined at the object construction, returns null". The thing to remember is that `parentNode` **moves** the tree position to the parent, and then `nextSibling` **moves** to the next sibling of the parent if it has one, otherwise the loop continues climbing up the tree.